# How to determine which scripts in my ~/Shell directory are causing my ~/.zshrc file to take so long to be loaded?

Tags: performance, shell, zshrc

I have a `~/.zshrc` file that executes all the top-level shell scripts in my `~/Shell` directory, these top-level scripts in turn execute the lower-level scripts. For example, scripts in `~/Shell/programs` (the so called "lower-level scripts") are executed by the top-level `~/Shell/09-programs.sh` script. I have noticed lately that running `~/.zshrc` has become much slower than it used to be and I would like to know if there are any methods to determine which script (or set of scripts) in my `~/Shell` directory are causing it to become so slow. It would also be helpful to know the precise line number in each script that causes the script to become so slow. If you would like to see my `~/.zshrc` file and `~/Shell` scripts [here](https://github.com/fusion809/opensuse-scripts) is their GitHub repository that I update regularly.

Comment: Does running in debug mode with `zsh -x` help show the issue?

Comment: Especially if you set a `PS4` which dumps both line number and timestamp.

Comment: @Zlemini works great. CharlesDuffy care to give an example of what I should set PS4 to, as I am interested in line number and timestamp so I can see how long each script takes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
PS4=':[%*]:%x:%I+' zsh -x -l -i
```

will run a new login shell with each line executed preceded by a second-accurate timestamp, the filename and line number from which it was defined.

---

Incidentally, the bash equivalent to this looks something like:

```
PS4=':[\t]:$BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO+' bash -x -l -i
```

...though personally, I might use `$SECONDS` in that case rather than `\t`, to get an integer number of seconds since shell invocation.

Comment: Hmm, nope this doesn't work. Returns nothing, just goes onto the next line. Thought it would that's why I accepted it temporarily.

Comment: ...if it's in a script, then you want `PS4=':[%*]:%x:%I+'; set -x` -- the code in the answer is given to be run at an interactive prompt (and what it logs is the code run by your dotfiles).

Comment: It might, but I wouldn't know given that I am already running Zsh as my shell so I wouldn't be able to tell the difference unless I saw a heap of output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136563/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-brenton-horne).